# How to read points value hovering mouse pointer on the points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

I am new to QGIS and learning daily, and I find it very interesting day by day. I have come up with a problem here.  I stacked points on a sentinel2 image.  The points data I imported from a CSV file; the CSV file contains latitude, longitude and their corresponding values. I can see points scattered over the image. Finally, I want to read those points' value hovering the mouse cursor over the points. I can see values while opening the attribute table, but I couldn't figure out how to read those points' value using the mouse cursor. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some solutions :

- In the point layer properties, go to the [Display tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties) and select the field as `Display name` with the dropdown list (or set an expression). Now, with the identify tool, when you right-click on a point feature on the canvas, the value is displayed. If multiple points are stacked, a list of all values appears.
- In the point layer properties or in the [layer styling panel](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?#layer-styling-panel), you can go to the label tabs and configure labels for displaying data or expression next to the features.
- If you use the [identify tool](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?#identify), you can read all attributes for the selected feature.

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation of qgis](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#display-properties)

> The Display tab helps you configure fields to use for feature identification:
>
> The Display name: based on a field or an expression. This is:
>
> - the label shown on top of the feature information in the Identify tool results;
> - the field used in the locator bar when looking for features in all layers;
> - the feature identifier in the attribute table form view;
>
> the map tip information, i.e. the message displayed in the map canvas when hovering over a feature of the active layer with the Show Map Tips icon pressed. Applicable when no HTML Map Tip is set.
>
> The HTML Map Tip is specifically created for the map tips: it’s a more complex and full HTML text mixing fields, expressions and html tags (multiline, fonts, images, hyperlink…).

Example from docs:

[image: maptip]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use the **Identify tool** (in the Attributes toolbar) and click on the feature to see all the feature attributes in the Identify window.

[image]

Or turn on **Map Tips** (in the Attributes toolbar) to see an attribute when you hover over the  feature.

- You can choose which attribute is displayed in the Map Tip in the layer properties dialog > display. Or use HTML code to define a combination of attributes to display.
- You can change how long it takes for Map Tips to appear in the Settings menu > Options > Canvas and Legend.

[image]